# java - new inetaddress without checked exception

Tags: java

I want instances of InetAddress but don't want to put it in a try-catch like every factory method of that class forced to :

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByAddress(ipAddr);
```

Is there anyway to instantiate InetAddress from String ip that does not throw any checked exception?

Comment: I'm just looking for another ways of having InetAddress instances without checked exceptions, performance is my concern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. `InetAddress.getByAddress(...)` throws a [`UnknownHostException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/net/UnknownHostException.html)  which is a **checked exception** because it is a subclass of [`Exception`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Exception.html). You **must** handle every checked excpetion by either catching it or throwing it yourself. There is no way around this. Somewhere in you code you will have to catch it or your program will crash.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 2 ways to handle that. 
First you put it into try-catch block which you want to avoid and other way is to throw this exception further using **throws** keyword:

```
public static static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        method();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void method() throws UnknownHostException {
    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByAddress(null);

}
```

And handle it when you invoke this method using try-catch

Comment: It depends what exactly he want to achieve. He doesn't want to handle that so there is some reason. I just showed him possibilities

Comment: Like I said I just show him what he can do because he asked for that. He will decide if it helps him or not